# Get missing number sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

In table i have field pwd which goes like this 001 , 002, 003 , 004 .

To get highest value of that i go like this

```
 ("SELECT pwd FROM users WHERE pwd= (SELECT max(pwd) FROM users)")
```

That way i got number 004. To increment it and add again to table i use

```
biggest= CInt((SQLDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)))
Dim test As String = "000" & biggest
txtpwd.Text = test.Substring(test.Length - 3)
test2 = test.Substring(test.Length - 3)
```

But what if i want to find the first available number ( missing one ) . Example if i have

```
001, 002, 003 ,005 , 006 , 007 , 009 , 013.
```

I want to grab the number `004`. How can i do that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way i will get all of the missing numbers in array and then i use row index 0 to get only the first one.

```
select u1.pwd+1 as firstmissing
  from users as u1
       left outer join users as u2
                    on u2.pwd=u1.pwd+1
 where u2.pwd is null
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery (presuming sql-server):

```
SELECT MIN(u.pwd) + 1 AS FirstMissing
FROM users u
WHERE (u.pwd + 1) <> (SELECT TOP 1 u2.pwd 
                      FROM users u2
                      WHERE u2.pwd > u.pwd)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a27d6/2/0)</kbd>

If you want to do that in memory since you already have the `DataSet` you could use following Linq-To-DataSet query. But i strongly advise against filtering on client side.

```
Dim rows = SQLDataset.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
Dim missing = From row In rows
              Let id = row.Field(Of Int32)(0)
              Let nextId = rows.Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)(0)).
                                Where(Function(idNext) idNext > id).
                                OrderBy(Function(idNext) idNext).
                                DefaultIfEmpty(-1).
                                First()
              Where nextId <> -1 AndAlso id + 1 <> nextId
              Select id + 1
Dim firstMissing As Int32 = missing.FirstOrDefault()
```

If it's actually a `string` in the `DataTable` you can use `Int32.Parse`:

```
Dim missing = From row In rows
              Let id = Int32.Parse(row.Field(Of String)(0))
              Let nextId = rows.Select(Function(r) Int32.Parse(r.Field(Of String)(0))).
                                Where(Function(idNext) idNext > id).
                                OrderBy(Function(idNext) idNext).
                                DefaultIfEmpty(-1).
                                First()
              Where nextId <> -1 AndAlso id + 1 <> nextId
              Select id + 1
```

Comment: Since im first time using LINQ what do i need to import ? 
`Error 1 Expression of type 'Object' is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider.`

Comment: @AnelHodzic: you need to use .NET >= 3.5 (check compiler settings) and add `Imports System.Linq`. Maybe you also need to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.

Comment: Please take a look on this http://pokit.org/get/?1edc7632b942d807b7f2746391d5df7e.jpg

Comment: I think you just missing a cast for `DataRow` in rows

Comment: @Eric: no, i've used `AsEnumerable()`. Maybe OP needs to declare `rows` as `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`. But that should not be necessary if he sets `Option Infer` to `On` (recommended).

Comment: `Option Infer` is `ON`  and works now. But http://pokit.org/get/?6f9f14650aed492df621b4cfa62eef44.jpg

Comment: @AnelHodzic: that is because i thought that the column is an `Integer` column(what it should be). If it's a string use `Int32.Parse()` to get the integer from string. So replace all   with `Int32.Parse(row.Field(Of String(0)))`

Comment: Trust me i'm trying for it but can you make that edit for me please ?

Comment: @AnelHodzic: i have added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much but here are the results. With this code i always get the last number in table example if i have 5,6,7,9 as a result i got the number 7. So i added `firstMissing + 1 ` , works as a charm. But then i found the problem.  This works perfect for first 9 numbers. When number over 9 is missing it show me only one character such as 1.

Comment: @AnelHodzic: but i'm pretty sure that is not related to the  LINQ query. It may be caused my string methods(f.e. `Substring`) that you use to display the value.

Comment: Well I'm not pretty sure because. All i do is add that value to my textbox. With this last edit instead of 10 it shows 0

Comment: @AnelHodzic: what does `missing.ToList()` contain? Those are the `Integers` in a `List(Of Int32)`. I think that you'll find the correct Id's there. If not, what strings do you really store?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75697/discussion-between-anel-hodzic-and-tim-schmelter).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Do you still remember me :) . I'm finally make it doing with this query i just need one edit from you. Is there any way by this query to see if there is no missing number to set to the highest + 1 as output ?

Comment: @AnelHodzic: i guess that is what i've mentioned already in the chat:  you could  check if `Dim anyMissing As Boolean = firstMissing = 0`. That works because `firstMissing` is only 0 if there were no gaps (0 is the deault value for integers which is returned from `FirstOrDefault`).

Comment: I made a mistake there. You posted your answer first . I upvoted it and wait to finish to accept. After we completed the chat i just marked as solved first answer didn't pay attention on that.You see i didn't commented at all on his answer because didnt helped me at all

Comment: Anyways sorry for misunderstanding you today. And thank you very much for your time you spend on me today.

Comment: @anel: but now you have unaccept it anyway. Do you have a nrw issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cater the case for the empty table.

```
declare @data table (Value char(3))

select ISNULL(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(10), MIN(Number)), 3), '001') AS FirstMissingValue
from
(
    -- Inner Table
    select Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value) Number 
    from @data
) data
where Value <> Number


insert @data values('001'), ('002'), ('003') ,('008'), ('006')

select ISNULL(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(10), MIN(Number)), 3), '001') AS FirstMissingValue
from
(
    -- Inner Table
    select Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value) Number 
    from @data
) data
where Value <> Number
```

Result

```
FirstMissingValue
-----------------
001

FirstMissingValue
-----------------
004
```

Comment: I guess that the values are actually stored as int, otherwiese OP's sql wouldn't work: `SELECT pwd FROM users WHERE pwd= (SELECT max(pwd) FROM users)`. I think that he converts them to string before he displays them.

Comment: Values are stored as Nvarchar(3) . I get the value as string (002) but the problem is when i want to increment it for i it to 003 i got 3 only. So i need to add 000 in front of that number and grab the right three characters to write in table again

Comment: @AnelHodzic It is because you casted the value by `CInt()` in the first place

Comment: @AnelHodzic: that's a lack of proper designing if you store the value as `varchar` instead of `int`. Formatting should be done where you display the value. You could also format it in the `SELECT` sql but don't store it.

Comment: Well even if its not i still cant increment the value 002 to 003 without converting it to number, incrementing, and converting to string again